# Auto-Inserting quotes does not work in c project Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Auto-Inserting quotes in printf and scanf does not work. quotes(" ") are working another places and c# codes  but when i write printf(") or scanf(") in c project, i have to insert enclosing quotes.

my version are resharper ultimate 2016.3.2 and visual studio ultimate 2013.

In Environment | Editor | Editor Behavior page of ReSharper options and the controls in the Braces and Parentheses section are set default.

Answer (score 1):

it is a bug. i posted the question in jetbrains community support and one of them reported it as bug.
go to 
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000157390-Auto-Inserting-quotes-does-not-work-in-c-project